# How does CMake command find_package work with variable <name>_DIR

Tags: cmake

I have a question about the CMake command `find_package`.

For example, when I want use OpenCV, I can set the variable `OpenCV_DIR`. `OpenCV_DIR` also has a default value. But which command generates this variable `OpenCV_DIR`,  and when?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Behind the scenes, the find_package command is running a CMake file.  This file is executed as your CMake file is being run, when they are called by your CMake file.  These files (ex, FindOpenCV.cmake) set the variables in question.

When I am having issues with a find_package command, I often gain some clarity by reading through the corresponding FindWhateverPackage.cmake file.

Answer (score 0):

find_package operates in "module" or "configure" mode. By default, it tries first mode and if it fails to find the requested package, it tries second mode. In this mode it creates cache variable _DIR. [Link to documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.9/cmake.html#command%3afind_package)

FindOpenCV also sets this variable, if it finds OpenCVConfig.cmake, for more information [see here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/FindOpenCV.cmake)